# Jenkins, how to get a job by it's "displayName"

Tags: jenkins

Actually our `Jenkinsfile` deploys the last successful build

```
def installerBuildNumber = Jenkins.instance.getJob('Client Installer').getJob(cleanedInstallerBranch).getLastSuccessfulBuild().getNumber()
def clientBranch         = Jenkins.instance.getJob('Client Installer').getJob(cleanedInstallerBranch).getBuildByNumber(installerBuildNumber).getAction(ParametersAction).getParameter('CLIENT_BRANCH').value
...
```

But now I need to deploy a specified `tag`, for example `"1.0.7"`.

I've seen that the build `"1.0.7"` (in the picture) has a build number `85` but this is something that `Jenkins` file does not know.
The only available information is it's `displayName`, `"1.0.7"`.

How can I get the job via the `displayName` ?

[image]